# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity too Large in wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I am programming an application which uses the Service on server Side. I am trying to save a Word File with 50KB into to sql server. When I use the wsHttpBinding like this in web.Config of a service:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>       
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IECartService"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" ></binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>      
</bindings>   
</system.serviceModel>
```

there will be a error message:   "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity too Large"

but when I use the  basicHttpBinding in web.config of service :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IECartService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>      
</bindings>       
</system.serviceModel>
```

and this is in app.config on client side

```
 <system.serviceModel>
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>        

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IECartService"
                     maxBufferSize="2097152"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="2097152"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
                     closeTimeout="00:50:00"
                     openTimeout="00:50:00"
                     sendTimeout="00:50:00"
                     receiveTimeout="00:50:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="100000"
                    maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1085/ECartService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IECartService"
    contract="ECartServiceReference.IECartService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IECartService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The file could be saved to the Sql through the service:

How can I trace error ?

Answer (score 0):

WCF tracking is built on System.Diagnostics. To use tracking, you should define the tracking source in a configuration file or code.

You can configure tracking by editing the application's configuration file:

```
<configuration>  
   <system.diagnostics>  
      <sources>  
         <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"  
                    propagateActivity="true">  
            <listeners>  
               <add name="traceListener"
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />  
            </listeners>  
         </source>  
      </sources>  
   </system.diagnostics>  
</configuration>
```

For more detailed information about configuration tracking, you can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing

I also found a problem similar to the one you encountered:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsnotes/large-file-upload-failure-for-web-application-calling-wcf-service-413-request-entity-too-large

Comment: the message is : "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.", The file is around 50KB, and I change maxReceivedMessageSize to 2147483647, But no sucess

Comment: Is it because your configuration file has not been configured successfully?I did not see information about the endpoint in the configuration file of your server.